# Intent dialog prompts have stopped working

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot, alexa-interaction-model

I have a skill where I update the progress of students. I would say "Alexa, tell the tracker to add progress for [student]", it would then reply, "What is [student] working on?" and I would respond and it would write a record for that student to the DB (it also uses the ChatGPT API to see if there are any relevant worksheets to be added) and then respond that it has updated the progress for that student.

Two days ago, it stopped responding after asking what the student was working on.

The log simply says "Internal Service Error". When using the test environment, it asks the question and the response is "No Content".

It's like it's stopped sending through the data for the second Slot.

This is true of all the intents where it has a follow up question/dialog (I have others that remind me to create videos - I say the students name, then it asks me to describe the video - this too has stopped working with the same symptoms).

Has there been any changes to the toolkit, or have I messed something up somehow?

I've tried to recreate the Intent (created a new one called "Update" instead of "Add", and the output is the same. I can see from the log that the correct lambda method has fired, but it never gets to the handler code itself.